# How to find only those Schema.SObjectType types that are visible in the Schema Builder

Tags: describesobject, schema-builder, schema

I can find a map of all `String -> Schema.SObjectType` types by invoking `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`.

However, that includes a lot of object types I'm not interested in (like `casecomment`, `processinstance` or `apexlog`)

How can I find only those that are available in the Schema Builder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short after taking a deeper looker at this for you, I have to conclude the answer to your question is that you can only be partially successful in emulating the filters used by Schema Builder...

[image]

[image]

[image]

The **isCustom** method will help with the first obviously, the second two are harder to separate. The following uses the fact that Schema Builder seems to favour objects with Record Types (via **getRecordTypeInfos**). So I based further filtering on this. Note that this is governed method so some filtering on **isCreateable** objects was also needed. Thus some accessible (but not createable objects) are eliminated sadly.

Anyway, since I spent some time on this for you, I thought I would share anyway. Hopefully this gives you some thoughts and if nothing else a conclusion you can move forward with some other approach or variation on this on. Enjoy!

Following is the best I think you will achieve to cover Custom vs Standard.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
Set<String> standardObjects = new Set<String>();
Set<String> customObjects = new Set<String>();
for(Schema.SObjectType d : gd.values())
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ds = d.getDescribe();
    if(!ds.isCreateable())
      continue;
    if(ds.isCustom() == false && ds.getRecordTypeInfos().size() > 0)
        standardObjects.add(ds.getName());
    else if(ds.isCustom())
        customObjects.add(ds.getName());
}
List<String> sortedNames = new List<String>(customObjects);
sortedNames.sort();
for(String name : sortedNames)
  System.debug('Custom object: ' + name);
sortedNames = new List<String>(standardObjects);
sortedNames.sort();
for(String name : sortedNames)
  System.debug('Standard object: ' + name);
```

This results in the following, which gets pretty close, but no cigar....

> 01:53:17.135 (135755000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Account
>
> 01:53:17.135 (135835000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Campaign
>
> 01:53:17.135 (135903000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: CampaignMember
>
> 01:53:17.135 (135972000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Case
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136045000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Contact
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136117000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: ContentVersion
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136188000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Contract
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136259000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Event
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136326000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Idea
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136393000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Lead
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136465000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Opportunity
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136534000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Product2
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136601000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Solution
>
> 01:53:17.136 (136668000)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Standard object: Task

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain why to use  `isCreateable()` instead of `isAccessible()`?

Answer (score 0):

What I first used is to check for objects that have a `Name` field.

Using that you will get the objects that also appear in the Schema Builder and (from what I can see) not the objects that we're not interested in.

However, that will result in too many Object describes , so that won't really work. (edit: describe limits have been lifted since Summer14, so this *will* work!)

I ended up using

```
sObjectType == 'Account' || sObjectType == 'Lead' || sObjectType == 'Opportunity' || sObjectType == 'Contact' || schema.getDescribe().isCustom()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/59925/352 (solution to list all standard and custom objects ignoring system objects)